# Can I disable the login prompt for MS CRM 2011 SDK if credentials are wrong?

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011

Right now I access the **CRM SDK** as follows

```
IServiceManagement<IDiscoveryService> serviceManagement =
                        ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IDiscoveryService>(discoveryUri);
ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
using (DiscoveryServiceProxy serviceProxy = new DiscoveryServiceProxy(new DiscoveryServiceProxy(serviceManagement, credentials))
{
    RetrieveOrganizationsRequest orgRequest = new RetrieveOrganizationsRequest();
    RetrieveOrganizationsResponse orgResponse =
                (RetrieveOrganizationsResponse)service.Execute(orgRequest);
    // do something with organisations
}
```

However, if the domain credentials are incorrect, a **Windows** login prompt appears (somewhere in `service.Execute`). I don't want that login prompt. I have worked around this issue by validating the credentials using `PrincipalContext` before passing them to the `DiscoveryServiceProxy`, but I'm not entirely happy with that.

Is there a way to disable the login prompt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone on the [CRM forums](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/665ca5aa-64c7-4f53-9249-f440270c30a7/can-i-disable-the-login-prompt-for-ms-crm-2011-sdk-if-credentials-are-wrong) told me what to do:

`credentials.ClientCredentials.SupportInteractive = false;`