# OrganizationServiceProxy: No authentication error when wrong password is setup

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm creating Organization service proxy object using following way:

```cs
[ThreadStatic]
public static OrganizationServiceProxy OrgServiceProxy;

// ...

sLog.DebugFormat("Get AuthenticationProviderType...");
AuthenticationProviderType _crmAuthType = this.GetServerType(parameters.DiscoveryUri);
sLog.DebugFormat("Get AuthenticationProviderType - DONE!");
// ...
sLog.Info("Perform metadata download (ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration)...");
IServiceConfiguration<IOrganizationService> _crmServiceConfiguration = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(parameters.OrgServiceUri);
sLog.Info("Perform metadata download (ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration) - DONE");
// ...
// enable proxy types
var behavior = new ProxyTypesBehavior() as IEndpointBehavior;
behavior.ApplyClientBehavior(_crmServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint, null);

// ...

public OrganizationServiceProxy GetServiceProxy(ICRMConnectionParameters parameters)
{
    // ...
    ClientCredentials clientCreds = new ClientCredentials();
    clientCreds.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = parameters.UserName;
    clientCreds.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = parameters.Password;
    clientCreds.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = parameters.Domain;        

    sLog.DebugFormat("Setup client proxy...");
    OrgServiceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(_crmServiceConfiguration, clientCreds);
    sLog.DebugFormat("Setup client proxy - DONE.");

    return OrgServiceProxy;
}
```

Just note here that AuthenticationProviderType and IServiceConfiguration are statically cached. This code above is part of class named CRMConnection.

I have one more abstract class (ProxyUser) which contains following property:

```cs
private CRMConnection conn;
// ...
protected OrganizationServiceProxy OrgServiceProxy
{
  get
  {
    //return orgService;
    return this.Conn.GetServiceProxy();
  }
}

protected CRMConnection Conn
{
  get
  {
    conn = conn ?? new CRMConnection();
    return conn;
  }
}
```

In another class that inherits ProxyUser I have method with following code:

```cs
ColumnSet columnSet = new ColumnSet();
ConditionExpression condition1 = new ConditionExpression("new_id", ConditionOperator.NotNull);

FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter.AddCondition(condition1);

QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression()
{
    EntityName = new_brand.EntityLogicalName,
    ColumnSet = columnSet,
    Criteria = filter,
    NoLock = true
};

EntityCollection res = OrgServiceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

And now we come to the point :)

If I setup correct parameters - organization service url, discovery service url, username, password and domain, everything works as expected. BUT, in case when wrong password is set, in line below, service is simply unresponsive. It doesn't happen anything.

```cs
EntityCollection res = OrgServiceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

Of course, I'm expecting authentication failed error. Any suggestions what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There should be a timeout at the very least.  No Exception is generated?

Comment: I tried to set timeout to 5sec. Same thing. Didn't get any exception. That's weird.

Comment: I'm assuming you're stepping through and debugging this?  Or are you just running it and checking some sort of log?

Comment: Both. In debugger, it comes to line 'OrgServiceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(query);' and stays there. OrgSerivceProxy is created, but nothing happens.

Comment: I'd try a WhoAmIRequest just to see if that does anything different.

Comment: I already tried that :) After OrgServiceProxy is created, before returning to ProxyUser, I tried with executing WhoAmIReq. Same thing :-/

Comment: Try removing the thread static Attribute.  There may be some threading logic that is causing it to pause

Comment: I found solution after moving logic to console app. See my answer. Anyway, thanx for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with adding line below in *GetServiceProxy* method - when *ClientCredentials* are created:

```
clientCreds.SupportInteractive = false;
```

I figured this out after I moved whole logic in console app. When wrong password is set and app is in debug mode, I'm getting windows login prompt. Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646645/can-i-disable-the-login-prompt-for-ms-crm-2011-sdk-if-credentials-are-wrong).